# Complex Analysis: Evaluating an Integral over C. where C is the contour |z| = 1.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've got a homework question that I believe requires me to use Laurent series/method of residues.

The question itself is: 
Evaluate $\int_C \frac{1}{z^2(z^2-16)}dz$ where C is the contour $|z| = 1$.
I'm confused by this question because it doesn't say anything about the orientation of C. 
I know that the function is not analytic at z = 0, 4, -4. However beyond that, i'm ashamed to say I don't even know how to approach this.

So far, I've tried breaking it into:
$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{z+4i} \frac{1}{z-4i}dz$. But I don't really know how to get the Taylor/Laurent series for these three pieces.

Am I approaching this in the right way?
Can somebody help me move forward?

Comment: The contour "|z|= 1" is the circle, of radius 1, centered at the origin.  Both 4i and -4i lie outside that contour so, immediately, those two parts contribute nothing to the integral.  You have reduced the problem to integrating $\frac{1}{z^2}$ around that circle.  One way to do that is to observe that, on that circle,$z= e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ going from 0 to $2\pi$.  $dz= ie^{i\theta}d\theta$ so the integral becomes $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-2i\theta} ie^{i\theta}d\theta= i\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-i\theta}d\theta$.

Comment: There is a very easy way to get the Taylor series for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-16}$; think about geometric series.  Then you just have to divide it by $z^2$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{z^2-16}$ factors as $\frac{1}{(z+4)(z-4)}$, not $4i$.  Not that it makes a lot of difference for this problem.

Comment: The question probably should have specified an orientation for $C$.  However you are going to find that the value of the integral is 0 so in fact it doesn't matter which way you orient it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orientation of $C$ does not matter here. The value of the integral is $0$ and you can prove it without any calculation! The only pole inside $C$ is $z=0$. Near $0$ the function $\frac 1 {z^{2}-16}$ is analytic and when you divide the power series of this analytic function by $z^{2}$ the residue becomes $0$. [ Residue is the coefficient of $\frac 1 z$. Note that the power series of this function has only **even powers** of $z$]. Hence the integral is $0$.